# How can I save as json that variable defined as base class?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for how to save the variable that defined as base class to json.

```
[Serializable]
class DataFile
{
    public Node root;

    public void Save()
    {
        ParentNode root = new ParentNode();
        root.m_Childs = new Node[2]();
        root.m_Name = "Root";
        ParentNode node0 = new ParentNode();
        ParentNode node1 = new ParentNode();
        node0.m_Name = "Node0";
        node1.m_Name = "Node1";
        root.m_Childs[0] = node0;
        root.m_Childs[1] = node1;

        JSonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Node
{
    public string m_Name;
}

[Serializable]
class ParentNode : Node
{
    public Node[] m_Childs;
}
```

The resulting `JsonUtility` with the above code only stores `m_Name` of `root` and `m_Childs` not.

How can I figure it out?

Comment: You know you can just [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66133750/edit) your question and add such an important info there right? ;)

Comment: In C#, please name public things using `PascalCase` for example: `public Node Root;`  and private things with `_camelCaseLeadingUnderscore`, like this: `private Node _root;` - this will also help you avoid basic mistakes like having a class level variable called `root` and a local level variable also called `root`: `ParentNode root = new ParentNode();` and not knowing which you're referring to. You've gone to great effort to populate a variable that you simply throw away because you never actually use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you serialize you are serializing the value of

```
public Node root;
```

which only has a

```
public string m_Name;
```

not the local variable

```
ParentNode root = new ParentNode();
```

Additionally the (de)serializer will use the type you give it, not the type it could possibly be by inheritance. The only type known to `DataFile` is `Node` so it will only serialize fields known to that type. And the only type known to `ParentNode` are childs of type `Node`. If you need to store the information contained in a `ParentNode` then you'll have to use fields of that type instead!

---

I guess it should maybe rather be

```
[Serializable]
class DataFile
{
    public ParentNode root;

    public void Save()
    {
        var node0 = new ParentNode{
            m_Name = "Node0"
        };

        var node1 = new ParentNode{
            m_Name = "Node1"
        };

        root = new ParentNode{
            m_Name = "Root",
            m_Childs = new[]{node0, node1}
        };

        JSonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Node
{
    public string m_Name;
}

[Serializable]
class ParentNode : Node
{
    // Again the only type known to ParentNode is childs of type Node
    // if you need ParentNode then the type has to be that also in the 
    // ParentNode class
    public ParentNode[] m_Childs;
}
```

Comment: Then, I would like to receive various classes that inherit Node as a Node[], is there any way?
Do I have to adjust the type to the original type?

Answer (score 0):

As with other json libraries, the Json Utility, which is provided by Unity by default, was unable to determine what type of content was stored when load from json. I have decided to use scriptable object, but if you really want to use Json Utility, you can use ISerializationCallbackReceiver to make commands before and after Json serialization.